# Dockerfile's RUN command doesn't find script

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-toolbox

Using Docker Toolbox on Windows 10, Docker cannot build an image from my Dockerfile because it doesn't find a script (`install-composer`) that was copied to the image.

```
FROM php:7.2.5-apache

COPY scripts/install-composer /usr/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/install-composer
RUN /usr/bin/install-composer
```

The error I get, when reating the last `RUN` command, is:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/install-composer: not found
```

The `chmod` command does work however, indicating the file does actually exist in the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple problem but a very misleading error.

The problem was caused by wrong file endings. Git was set up to convert the project files into Windows (`CRLF`) file endings. I reinstalled Git with the setting "Checkout as-is, commit Unix-style", deleted and recloned the repository, and it fixed the problem.

When it comes to explaining the misleading and confusing error message, my guess is that the file `install-composer` was actually found and executed. What it is actually saying was that  was not found. This empty name was simply the `CR` caught between two `LF` (in other words, an empty line) and `sh` interpreted it as a call to a script file.

Answer (score 0):

Try and group those `RUN` commands:

```
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/install-composer && \
    ls -alrth /usr/bin/install* && \
    /usr/bin/install-composer
```

That way, you will see if the file is indeed copied and present.

You can also try, for your second RUN:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/install"
```

(assuming your script uses bash, and you have a bash installed in your image)

Comment: I tried both, but it did not work. The problem seems to be resolved with sh.